# ExtJS Direct--pass scope to method

Tags: java, javascript, extjs, ext-direct

I'm using the ExtJS Direct proxy and need to know how to pass scope when calling a method. Currently im doing this

```
myapp.direct.action.mygridservice.getGridData("123",this.getSearchCbo().getValue(), function(p_,resp_){
          //do something
      }, this);
```

on the java method I added a third param for scope with type String but i still get an error that "this" is undefined

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.- The scope parameter that you are passing is not to the backend but to your callback function. (function to execute once the server side responds)**

**2.- If you want to pass more information to the backend it needs to be passed in an object before the callback function and the scope.**

Example:

```
    var jsObject = {//put all the info you need to send to the server so you dont have 50 params}

    myapp.direct.action.mygridservice.getGridData("123",comboValue, jsObject someFunction, this);
```

Passing **this** as the scope will enable you to access some variables that otherwise will not be reachable.

Do:

```
console.log(this);
```

on your callback function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
loadData: function () {    
  RemoteManager.loadData(param1,param2, this.callbackLoadData, this);
},

callbackLoadData: function (result, e) {
   var t = e.getTransaction();
   var ctl = t.args[t.args.length - 1];
}
```

Comment: @stackato this would be available on callbackLoadData not on your backend method

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should wrap your callback function.

Check this links.

[Passing Extra Data to Callbacks](http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/documentation/browser/extra-data.html)
https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?188184-set-scope-of-Ext.Direct-callback-handler